# How can the Nielsen family exist in Eve's World?

Tags: dark

In Dark season 3 we learn that:

> Hannah Kahnwald had an affair with Egon Tiedermann after time traveling to 1954 and from this affair, Siljia is born. Siljia is eventually sent back in time to the beginning of the 20th century where she gives birth to both Hanno (Noah) and Agnes.

Since the Nielsen family stems from Agnes Nielsen, and since we also learn that:

> Ulrich time travels to 1986 on the day of the apocalypse in Eve's World while Hannah stays behind in 2019 as is implied to have a miscarriage of the child she was bearing.

Given the above, how is it possible for the Nielsen family (and Noah for that matter) to exist in Eve's World? Also, since Hannah never traveled to 1954, how is it possible that Katharina Nielsen is named Katharina since Hanna wasn't there to "suggest" the name to Helene Albers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About 42 minutes into episode 6 of season 3, Eve says "It's time. Adam has moved each of his tokens into position. It's time we do the same." Then we see she is standing in front of a bunch of the versions of the characters from her universe, near the apparatus that creates the dark matter time portal, and telling them what each of their time-traveling missions is to be. When she comes to the older version of Egon from Eve's world, she says "Egon, you must create your past to preserve the family tree." Then later in the episode, there's a montage showing what's going on in Eve's world right before the apocalypse, and around 53 minutes in we see a scene where the pregnant Hannah of this world has blood all over her dress, and then the older Egon walks in the door. The idea here is that she's just had a miscarriage, so she won't have Ulrich's baby, and that Egon is going to save Hannah from the apocalypse. And Eve's command to "create your past to preserve the family tree" implies that he will take her back to 1954 to meet his own younger self, and Hannah and the younger Egon will have an affair which will result in the birth of Silja just like in Adam's world.

This is mostly confirmed on the [Dark official website](https://dark.netflix.io/en)--if you first select that you want spoilers up to to season 3 episode 8, the [timeline for Hannah Nielsen from Eve's world](https://dark.netflix.io/en/event-timeline/hannah-nielsen-b) says "On the day of the apocalypse, Hannah suffers a miscarriage. Minutes before Winden is devastated, old Egon Tiedemann rescues her on behalf of Erit Lux." They don't directly say that the "rescue" involves taking her back to 1954 but it seems to what's intended.

Comment: I did notice Eve sending Egon through the apparatus but I totally failed to notice the scene between him and Hannah (which left me confused when Even told Egon to create his past as the Tiedermann family tree is non-recursive).